# FB.scrollTo() not working on my FB tab

Tags: facebook

Ive tried to be sneaky and written a FB app, for a tab on a Page... the app allows you to paste in some HTML code, and then displays it on your tab.

I then paste in the html code for an iframe (which I have given a specific height to).  The iframe pulls in content from a Wordpress site.  But because some pages are longer than others, and the iframe is set to 1400px to accomodate all page content without scroll bars appearing, you have to manually scroll up the page.

Ive tried the following the the APP code to scroll the FB page to the top...

```
<body style="overflow: hidden;"> 

    <!-- echo out iframe page code -->

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
     appId: 123456789, 
     status: true, 
     cookie: true, 
     xfbml: true
    });

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
    };

    //Load the JavaScript SDK asynchronously
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>

 </body>
```

but the scroll to top thing isnt working... any input appreciated!

Just occurred to me that FB.scrollTo might well be working, but because that App file is not being reloaded when i navigate within the embedded iframe, its not going to call it... so I need to trigger FB.scrollTo when the new iframe content loads...?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/ (FB.Canvas.scrollTo)

However, this function has only one purpose: scrolling to a certain position on your **canvas app** (https://apps.facebook.com/yourapp). It doesn't work if you manually insert an iframe either. On a canvas app, your app is being loaded in an iframe automatically.

Also, this only works if you set your Canvas Height to Settable.